# Trying to unpickle estimator SVC from version 0.19.1 when using version 0.22.1 error

Tags: environment-variables, version

I'm trying to run some demo example with speech WAV segmentation.

```
   from pyAudioAnalysis import audioSegmentation as aS
    [flagsInd, classesAll, acc, CM] = aS.mtFileClassification("diarizationExample.wav", 
"svmSM", "svm", True, 'dar.segments.txt')
```

the error I get:

```
C:\Users\Kenzhegaliyev_EK\AppData\Local
\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:318: 
UserWarning:


    Trying to unpickle estimator SVC from version 0.19.1 

    when using version 0.22.1. This might lead 
to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
          UserWarning)
```

It's some old sklearn's svc estimator.

How should i fix it? Uninstall sklearn and install the version 0.19.1?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late answer, but as the issue is still active in many codes, so i wrote the answer hope so it will help someone.

> Trying to unpickle estimator SVC from version 0.19.1  when using
> version 0.22.1.

The error is clear it is telling you that when the pickle file was created, it was created using the version 0.19.1 but you are now decoding your pickle file from different version which is 0.22.1.

so the warning is clear that code may break or some thing won't work of course.

To address the problem you have either 1 of the 2 options

**Option 1**
Create pickle file from the same version. E.g. if creating in differnt machine then you have to upgrade to the latest scikit-learn

**Option 2**
In the machine where you are decoding pickle file, downgrade your scikit-learn to the version mentioned in the warning, e.g. in your case 0.19.1
you can use pip command to do this

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.19.1 #python 2
pip3 install scikit-learn==0.19.1 #python 3
```

the command will automatically remove previous version and install the new one specified.

Answer (score 0):

Pickle is the standard serialization format for Python objects, but it is insecure because it can run arbitrary code (see [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-pickle)).

As mentioned in [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_persistence.html#security-maintainability-limitations) documentation, `pickle`, and by extension `joblib` have issues with security and maintainability. Even if successful, operations performed on such data might results in different and unexpected results.

Scikit-learn recommends using [skops](https://skops.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), a more secured Python library to share scikit-learn based models. The API is also similar to `pickle`.

```py
# installation
pip install skops

# Usage:
from skops.io import dump, load
# save model
dump(clf, "my-model.skops")
# load already saved model
loaded = load("my-model.skops", trusted=True)
```